# I cannot get my bottomnavigationview to display a new URL when an item within it is clicked. How can I fix this?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have looked up my issue and couldn't find anything that successfully resolved the problem for me. I need to implement my bottomnavigationview in my fragments because they are the ones that contain the webview, not the main activity. It was working the day before, and then I overhauled my app a bunch and I can't figure out what the roadblock is now.

MainFragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends Fragment{

private WebView webview;
private NavigationView nvDrawer;
private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
private Toolbar toolbar;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //returning our layout file
    //change R.layout.yourlayoutfilename for each of your fragments
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    webview = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.homewebView);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    webview.loadUrl(newurl);
    // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) view.findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_courses:
                    webview.loadUrl("https://canvas.thelatinschool.org/courses");
                    break;
                case R.id.action_calendar:
                    webview.loadUrl("https://canvas.thelatinschool.org/calendar");
                    break;
                case R.id.action_inbox:
                    webview.loadUrl("https://canvas.thelatinschool.org/inbox");
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    ((DrawerLocker) getActivity()).setDrawerEnabled(false);
    return view;
}
/.../
}
```

Its xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="org.thelatinschool.canvasgrades.MainActivity">

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/homewebView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: can you please elaborate your issue in more detail?

Comment: @Akashkumar so basically my bottom navigation bar is visible properly and when I select an item on that bar, the item becomes highlighted but nothing actually happens, the fragment just stays the way it is. What it is supposed to do is change the URL displayed by the webview of the fragment as you can see above.